# Rails query working in console but not in the controller

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

I have an application that has a table Doctors with a name field. The users can put any version of the name in there they want. I'm trying to sort the records based on last name(last word in the string) before I display them in the index view.

I came up with a query that works in the console but gets an error when running it in the controller.

The query is as follows:

```
current_user.doctors.select("doctors.*, split_part(doctors.name, ' ', -1) AS lastname").order('lastname ASC')
```

My table migration:

```
class CreateDoctors < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    create_table :doctors do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :field
      t.string :address
      t.string :phone
      t.string :fax
      t.string :website
      t.string :portal
      t.binary :active, default: true
      t.string :group

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My controller code:

```
def index
  @doctors = 
       current_user.doctors.select("doctors.*, split_part(doctors.name, ' ', -1) AS lastname").order('lastname ASC')
end
```

And my view code:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag Doctor.new %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "doctors" do %>
  <% @doctors.each do |doctor| %>
    <%= render 'doctor_index', doctor: doctor %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The error I get is the following:

```
17:16:53 web.1  | Started GET "/doctors" for ::1 at 2024-03-16 17:16:53 -0600
17:16:53 web.1  |   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
17:16:53 web.1  | Processing by DoctorsController#index as HTML
17:16:53 web.1  |   User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:16:53 web.1  |   Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
17:16:53 web.1  |   Rendering doctors/index.html.erb within layouts/application
17:16:53 web.1  |   Rendered shared/_nav-tabs.erb (Duration: 1.2ms | Allocations: 482)
17:16:53 web.1  |   Doctor Count (21.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(doctors.*, split_part(doctors.name, ' ', -1) AS lastname) FROM "doctors" WHERE "doctors"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 2]]
17:16:53 web.1  |   ↳ app/views/doctors/index.html.erb:12
17:16:53 web.1  |   Rendered doctors/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 83.8ms | Allocations: 17358)
17:16:53 web.1  |   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 84.2ms | Allocations: 17477)
17:16:53 web.1  | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 254ms (ActiveRecord: 42.9ms | Allocations: 54020)
17:16:53 web.1  |
17:16:53 web.1  |
17:16:53 web.1  |
17:16:53 web.1  | ActionView::Template::Error (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
17:16:53 web.1  | LINE 1: ...OUNT(doctors.*, split_part(doctors.name, ' ', -1) AS lastnam...
17:16:53 web.1  |                                                              ^
17:16:53 web.1  | ):
17:16:53 web.1  |      9:   </div>
17:16:53 web.1  |     10:   <%= turbo_frame_tag Doctor.new %>
17:16:53 web.1  |     11:   <%= turbo_frame_tag "doctors" do %>
17:16:53 web.1  |     12:     <% if @doctors.count != 0 %>
17:16:53 web.1  |     13:       <% @doctors.each do |doctor| %>
17:16:53 web.1  |     14:         <%= render 'doctor_index', doctor: doctor %>
17:16:53 web.1  |     15:       <% end %>
17:16:53 web.1  |
```

Running it in the console produces the results I'm looking for, which is a list of doctors records ordered by last name.

I'm sure it's a conversion problem from the Rails query to the psql query but I can't figure out how to rewrite it so that it works the way I want.  I am confused why it works in the console but not the controller though.

Comment: Your view code does not match the view code in the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is:

```
SELECT COUNT(doctors.*, split_part(doctors.name, ' ', -1) AS lastname)
```

Where did the count come from? Let's look at the error message.

```
17:16:53 web.1  |      9:   </div>
17:16:53 web.1  |     10:   <%= turbo_frame_tag Doctor.new %>
17:16:53 web.1  |     11:   <%= turbo_frame_tag "doctors" do %>
17:16:53 web.1  |     12:     <% if @doctors.count != 0 %>
17:16:53 web.1  |     13:       <% @doctors.each do |doctor| %>
17:16:53 web.1  |     14:         <%= render 'doctor_index', doctor: doctor %>
17:16:53 web.1  |     15:       <% end %>
```

It's from `<% if @doctors.count != 0 %>`. If `select` is used with [`count`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count) it will count the selected columns.

As you probably realized, there is no point to checking `@doctors.count`; if @doctors is empty `@doctors.each` will do nothing. The extra count query is an extra query and also introduces a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), in this particular case a probably inconsequential one.

You probably deleted the line locally, but did not save or deploy it.

---

If all you want to do is order by last name, you can use `order` directly and leave your selected columns alone.

```
current_user.doctors.order("split_part(doctors.name, ' ', -1) asc")
```

If you do this frequently, and there are many doctors, you'll want to do an indexed query. You could add an [index on that particular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html)...

```
create index doctor_lastname_idx on doctors(split_part(name, ' ', -1))
```

Or you could add it as a generated column. You could add a lastname column to the doctors table and do this in a before_save [callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)...

```
class Doctor < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  before_save :set_lastname

  private def set_lastname
    self[:lastname] = name.rpartition(/\s+/).last
  end
end
```

Or you can do it directly in the database with a [real virtual column](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#generated-columns).

```
change_table :users do |t|
  t.virtual :lastname, type: :string, as: 'split_part(doctors.name, ' ', -1)', stored: true
  t.index(:lastname)
end
```

Comment: Alternatively, change `@doctors.count` to `@doctors.length`

Comment: Thanks! I had changed the code locally but hadn't saved it so was still picking up the previous version.  I needed a bit more caffeine that day!